# "Google Chrome bookmark sync" equivalent in firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons

In the beginning Google Chrome seemed fine but recently its been crashing too many times. I want to move back to Firefox.

I really love the way Google Chrome syncs bookmarks to 'Google Docs'. Is there any extension which gives this functionality in firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) which does bookmark backup and sync across machines. I use it with firefox and it works really well. It does add seconds to the app shutdown time though.

Comment: +1 as it is also available for many browsers - Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla Weave (now called [Sync](https://mozillalabs.com/sync/)) does this pretty well. It will also sync history, tabs and saved passwords.

The data is heavily encrypted and you can even host your own server instead of using the one Mozilla provides.